# How can return a nested table a function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I Take the data to V_EMP nested table with Bulk Collect. Between the Begin-End how can I call the function?

```sql
DECLARE

    TYPE T_REC IS RECORD
    (
    T_TITLE VARCHAR2,
    T_YEAR NUMBER(2,1)
    );

    TYPE T_EMP IS TABLE OF T_REC%TYPE;
    V_EMP T_EMP;
    Z_EMP T_EMP;
    V_EMP_ID NUMBER := 101;

    FUNCTION HIST(V_EMP_ID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE)
        RETURN V_EMP;

    BEGIN

        SELECT JOB_TITLE T_TITLE, ROUND((END_DATE - START_DATE) / 365,1) T_YEAR
        BULK COLLECT INTO V_EMP
        FROM JOB_HISTORY INNER JOIN JOBS USING(JOB_ID)
        WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = V_EMP_ID
        ORDER BY START_DATE;

        RETURN V_EMP;
    END HIST;

BEGIN

    Z_EMP := HIST(V_EMP_ID);

    FOR C IN (SELECT T_TITLE, T_YEAR FROM Z_EMP)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C.T_TITLE, C.T_YEAR);
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your types aren't quite declared correctly.

In your type `T_REC`, you need to declare the size of the `VARCHAR2` column.  I've used `100` as an example here:

```sql
    TYPE T_REC IS RECORD
    (
    T_TITLE VARCHAR2(100),
    T_YEAR NUMBER(2,1)
    );
```

Secondly, the line

```sql
    TYPE T_EMP IS TABLE OF T_REC%TYPE;
```

is incorrect: `T_REC` is itself a type so you don't specify the `%TYPE` attribute for it.  Try the following instead.

```sql
    TYPE T_EMP IS TABLE OF T_REC;
```

There are also some problems with the way you have defined your function:

```sql
    FUNCTION HIST(V_EMP_ID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE)
        RETURN V_EMP;

    BEGIN
        -- ...
```

The `RETURN` clause requires a type to be used, but `V_EMP` is a local variable. Also, instead of ending the declaration with a semicolon you need to include the keyword `IS` to tell the PL/SQL compiler that the following block forms the body of the function.  Putting these changes together, we have:

```sql
    FUNCTION HIST(V_EMP_ID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE)
        RETURN T_EMP
    IS
    BEGIN
        -- ...
```

---

After fixing these problems with the declarations, we can then look at the `BEGIN` block at the bottom.   The first problem is that you can't write `SELECT T_TITLE, T_YEAR FROM Z_EMP` to query from a variable that contains a nested table.  Instead, you have to wrap it in a call to `TABLE`, i.e. `SELECT T_TITLE, T_YEAR FROM TABLE(Z_EMP)`.

However, doing that won't work.  You'll get the error `PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements` if you try.  This is because you can't run a SQL query on types only declared within a PL/SQL block.  You can instead loop over the values in the returned collection using the following:

```sql
    IF Z_EMP.COUNT = 0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no records');
    ELSE
        FOR i IN Z_EMP.FIRST .. Z_EMP.LAST
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Z_EMP(i).T_TITLE || ', ' || Z_EMP(i).T_YEAR);
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
```

Note that in this case we need to check for the collection having no records: if the collection is empty, `Z_EMP.FIRST` and `Z_EMP.LAST` will be `NULL` and you will get a `PL/SQL: numeric or value error` attempting to use them in a range in the `FOR` loop.   Also note that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` takes only one argument: to avoid an error here I concatenated the two values together with a comma between them.

Alternatively, if you really want to use a SQL query to read the values returned by your function, you have a little more work.  You would have to declare the types `T_REC` and `T_EMP` outside of your PL/SQL block, as follows:

```sql
CREATE TYPE T_REC IS OBJECT
(
    T_TITLE VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
    T_YEAR NUMBER(2,1)
);
/

CREATE TYPE T_EMP IS TABLE OF T_REC;
/
```

You would then remove the declaration of these types within your block.  You would also have to adjust the query inside your function: instead of selecting

```sql
        SELECT JOB_TITLE T_TITLE, ROUND((END_DATE - START_DATE) / 365,1) T_YEAR
```

and having these fields mapped into records, you would have to explicitly create a `T_REC` object from each selected row:

```sql
        SELECT T_REC(JOB_TITLE, ROUND((END_DATE - START_DATE) / 365,1))
```

Once you had done this, the loop at the bottom could be changed to the following:

```sql
        FOR C IN (SELECT T_TITLE, T_YEAR FROM TABLE(Z_EMP))
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C.T_TITLE || ', ' || C.T_YEAR);
        END LOOP;
```

You could also get rid of the check `Z_EMP.COUNT = 0` if you want to: the above loop won't report an error if `Z_EMP` is empty, although it won't generate any output.